# Espresso regex matcher in Kotlin

Tags: android, regex, kotlin, android-espresso, uitest

I wanted to create a custom regex matcher for Espresso so that I can check if the text on the screen contains time in format like `HH:mm` for example `23:34` or `04:23`

I have a regex matcher class:

```
class RegexMatcher(private val regex: String) :
    BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView::class.java) {
    private val pattern = Pattern.compile(regex)

    override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {
        description?.appendText("Checking the matcher on received view: with pattern=$regex")
    }

    override fun matchesSafely(item: TextView?) =
        item?.text?.let {
            pattern.matcher(it).matches()
        } ?: false
}
```

And a function:

```
private fun withPattern(regex: String): Matcher<in View>? = RegexMatcher(regex)
```

The text on the screen says: `Sometext 08:23` the time is of course dynamic

My UI check is written like this:

```
onView(withText(startsWith("Sometext"))).check(matches(withPattern("/(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/")))
```

But the test always fails and I don't know why. Even if I just use something as simple as `/^Sometext` it fails. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

Your regex pattern doesn't include the preceding part of the string. You'll want to include something to capture that `Sometext` portion. What you use to capture that beginning portion depends on what you expect it to be. If it will only ever be non-digits, you could use `.*` (matches any character, 0 to infinity times) or `\D*` (matches any non-digit character, 0 to infinity times). If you know you have specifications that, say, you'll always have a string that is something like `The time is: {time}`, you could simply add the specified string.

`/.*(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/`
`/\D*(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/`
`/The time is: (0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/`

I'd recommend playing around with a regex tool to get your regex just right. My preferred one is [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).